# Android in app purchase order id GPA 123456789

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Did google update or change any format for order Id in in-app purchases ? Recently I have 2 order id of the format GPA.1234-5678-9876-5432-12345.

Comment: I observed the same thing today. Normally, the orderId has the format

[your purchase id][dot][individual order id]

The first id could be used to identify faked payments (i.e. "Freedom Hack") because they cannot know the correct id.
Now we have "GPA" here, presumbly an abbreviation for "Google Payment". If those payments are real, they look like fakes and they fail. Very bad.

Comment: Same here (GPA.1333-0918-...). Saw it first time.

Comment: Can confirm this and had to create a patch last night to reflect this changes in the validation.. Now there's no real check available as before, what a shame :-(

Comment: Still getting those. Appearantly not a temporary bug.
Did anybody report this to Google yet? I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: We get hundreds of Android purchases per day. It appears this started on 22.07.2015. And there appears to be 2 new formats: 1. GPA instead of the purchase Id; and 2. with the purchase Id, but the second part of the orderId is broken up in to 4 groups of 4 characters separated by dashes

Comment: Been seing a lot of it lately but unlike some of the comments they loom legit.all were charged

Answer (score 0):

This change by Google means that you cannot just check the orderId to find if the payment is valid or faked.

You have to implement the signature check procedure like documented 
[here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html).

Comment: I dont understand your answer. You never really needed the orderId to verify a purchase, only the token received when the payment was completed.

Comment: The merchant ID in the orderId provided a quick check to flag suspicious orders.